# How can I reach this gold chest on the Bank Robbery level?

Tags: fistful-of-frags

I've noticed something on the 'Bank Robbery' map (the one with a big bank that has a vault in it and a huge rooftop area).  As I respawn, and hop across the stairway to grab a blue chest, I look across the way into a building I've never been in the rooftop of before and to my surprise, I see a gold chest!

[image: screenshot]

However, I *don't* see any way of getting up to that room.  The area below it doesn't have any staircase that I'm aware of, and it doesn't look like there's anything betweeen that balcony and the small rooftop on the other side to hop onto in order to reach that high.

How do I get this gold chest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this by watching another player do it - I didn't think it was possible, but it's easy once you know where to go.

First, from the position where I am (which you get to by crouch-jumping from the stairs to the right) you crouch-jump up to the railing on the left.  Once you're at the other end, there's a small ledge on the brown building with a horse-tying pole in front of it (almost not visible, but you can walk along it).  You jump on that, run across it, and hop up into the balcony to get the chest.

In the updated version of the map, there is also a doorway behind this area you can use to get up to the golden chest, but you can still perform this series of jumps as another way of getting up there.